# How do you specify a custom error message in Bootstrap for input fields

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm using Twitter-Bootstrap in .NET 4.0.   I'm not using any additional jquery validation plugins.

I have this code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Url" runat="server" required  Text=''  placeholder="enter the  URL" pattern="http://*"  messages="Must start with 'http://' or 'https://' "></asp:TextBox>
```

The Regex validation works if I type 'asdf' in:

[image]

My Question is: how do I customize the "Please match the requested format" error to say "Must start with 'http://' or 'https://'"?

As you can see I've tried "messages=".  I've also tried several others.

1. How do I customize the generic error message?
2. Is there any documentation anywhere for Bootstrap that has more info on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with bootstrap, rather this the implementation of html5 form input validation in your browser (Chrome, by the look of your screenshot).

When using the `pattern` attribute, you should use the `title` to provide additional help to the user ([see the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern)).

With `title="Must start with 'http://' or 'https://'"`, you should see something like (in Chrome, different browsers will render this differently):

[image: Input validation using the pattern and title attributes]

You could also try changing the input type to URL, which would give you a different message even without the title, but my own experience has been that sometimes the browser implemented validation can be a little frustrating.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize that at all.  It looks like IE 9 doesn't even use the validation. So, I guess I'll have to use some jquery validation after all.  Have you had any success implementing any?

Comment: To be honest it's not something I've had occasion to try doing yet. Good luck though :)

Answer (score 9):

if you want to change invalid message you can use oninvalid attribute.

`oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('User ID is a must')"`

hope this helps you.

Comment: But When I insert the title in the input field. that message continues showing validation not working. when I click on the submit button with valid value its stuck on email field. I am using here bootstrap validator also.